# How to connect to SQL Server via SQL Server Management Studio 2008?

Tags: sql-server, connection, ssms

I can't seem to get this to work. I have an IP address for a SQL Server. I have a login and password.

How can I connect to it and work with it?

Comment: Why can't you get it to work? Do you get an error?

Comment: Where is this SQL Server? On the same network as you?

Comment: How are you trying to connect? If you're using something like ADO.Net, what does your connection string look like?

Comment: The sql server is somewhere down town. I'm connecting through the internet.

I'm trying to connect with the management studio connect object explorer.

The error msg says that the server wasnt found.

Answer (score 1):

That is a typical scenario and if you are having trouble there is something off on the server side.

The server may not have tcp/ip exposed. You will want to talk to whomever is responsible for administering the server.

Also, make sure there are no port filters blocking 1433 on your side or server side i.e. firewalls.

Answer (score 1):

Check with you hosting provider or the company you're working with and find out what port the server is running on.  Once that is known you should be able to use the IP and port number to connect with Management Studio and your username/password.

In the server name field put the IP+comma+Port like so:

4.2.2.2,1433 (assuming your IP is 4.2.2.2 and the port number is 1433)